NextJS - Tailwind Css: Image to take half the screen and have footer adjust to that
I have an app with multiple pages with a navbar and a footer. On 2 pages(Of which is the home page) I have image/images that take up half the screen and I want to make it so the footer and the text inside adjusts itself based on the image/images.
Footer
How it looks like now
How I want it to be
I have already tried with display:flex; but then the footer and the text inside the footer goes under the home page. Now I've tried with position: absolute; on footer(along with other attributes - see globals.css).
What I'm using currently(position absolute):
This is the layout.ts file
 <main className="holder">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="body">{children}</div>
          <Footer />
        </main>

page.tsx(Home page)
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    router.push(
      `/search?location=${event.target.searchValue.value}&date=${event.target.dateValue.value}`,
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="pl-24 pb-9 pt-9">
      <div className="divGrid images phone:gap-3">
        <div className="col-span-2 relative">
          <Image src="/picture-1.png" alt="Picture 1" fill />
        </div>
        <Image src="/picture-2.png" alt="Picture 2" height={238} width={238} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="text-black font-bold">FIND THE BEST EVENTS</div>
        <h1 className="text-7xl font-bold">
          Are you looking for your next event?
        </h1>
        <div className="text-black my-7">
          Eventreg is a website that allows you to create events
          {'(date, location, number of allowed people,..)'}. Other users can
          book their attendance for these events.
        </div>
        <div className="text-black font-bold">FIND YOUR NEXT EVENT</div>
        <div className="text-black">
          Search for a specific events by choosing the date and writing the
          location.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="searchForm w-2/3">
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div className="flex">
            <div className="relative w-full">
              <div className="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none">
                <Image
                  src="/locationIcon.svg"
                  alt="Location icon"
                  height={20}
                  width={20}
                />
              </div>
              <input
                type="search"
                name="searchValue"
                id="searchValue"
                className="block w-full p-2.5 ps-10 text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-s-lg bg-gray-50 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                placeholder="Search by location"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="relative w-full">
              <input
                type="date"
                name="dateValue"
                id="dateValue"
                defaultValue={new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)}
                min="2018-01-01"
                max="2031-12-31"
                className="block w-full p-2.5 ps-10 text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-e-lg bg-gray-50 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                required
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="blue absolute top-0 end-0 p-2.5 text-sm font-medium h-full text-white rounded-e-lg border border-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-500"
              >
                <svg
                  className="w-4 h-4"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    strokeWidth="2"
                    d="m19 19-4-4m0-7A7 7 0 1 1 1 8a7 7 0 0 1 14 0Z"
                  />
                </svg>
                <span className="sr-only">Search</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


the classes necessary in globals.css
.searchForm {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}

.holder {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.body {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


What I tried(display:flex):
layout.ts
<main>
          <div className="display">
            <Navbar />
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </main>

globals.css
.display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}


Footer.tsx:
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="bg-white">
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center pl-24 pb-9 pr-24 pt-9">
        <Image
          src="/nextup-logo.png"
          alt="Nextup logo"
          height={100}
          width={100}
        />
        <p>All rights received</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  )
}



With ui issues its always a good idea to provide screenshots on what you currently have and the desired state.

I have used screenshots

based on your screenshots, you will either need to set a width on your footer, or move the footer code into your first column.

I think it because fill property on this image component
<image src="/picture-1.png" alt="picture 1" fill />

Just using width and height and remove the fill property
Edit:
after seeing the third screenshot, maybe you can use a method like this
<main>
  <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
    <Navbar />
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        {children}
        <Footer />
       </div> 
       <div>image comp in here</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</main>

But to be honest I'm confused why the footer has to be there? In appearance it's good, but in terms of functionality I don't think so.
The advice I gave also definitely has its drawbacks, such as the comp image will become part of the layout and carry over to the child comp just like the nav and footer.
additional suggestions:
When you add a src image it directly references a public folder like "/dummy.png" you have to use the width and height properties, to be honest it's annoying because usually the image resolution is bad.
Apart from this method, you can also use a method like this "import dummy from @/public/dummy.png", So later on in the image, just use src={dummy} and to set the width and height you can use className, this way the image resolution will match the original one.

I will try. Althrough I have already used width and height on the second image and the text it still went over. In the footer I have a logo on the left and text on the right - padding is equal on both sides. I updated my question to include the footer image and and footer code

Thanks, I will try your solution. I will try to make it work for the other pages cos the home page and 1 other page are the only ones who have an image/images that take half the screen. And to answer your question on why the footer has to be there, it's cos my client wants it to be there, it's not my app . I've been struggling with this for the past few days, trying different solutions, I want to give up but I can't and I won't
